# Convert a string into a stream correctly

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports System.Text

Namespace WindowScriptingObject
    <Guid("7448E08D-ED0F-4E23-B528-91937BB41756"), _
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
        Public Interface _WindowScriptingObject
        <DispId(1)> Function Decompress(ByVal value as String) As String
    End Interface

    <Guid("B146BF9E-78FC-4DB0-ABFE-9FF026B43E4D"), _
        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), _
        ProgId("WindowScriptingObject")> Public Class WindowScriptingObject
    Implements _WindowScriptingObject

    Public WindowScriptingObject()
        Public Function Decompress(ByVal value as string) As String Implements _WindowScriptingObject.Decompress
            Dim x As String
            '     on error resume next
            Dim xstream As New MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value))
            Dim mem2 As New IO.MemoryStream()
            'Dim streamMe As New StreamWriter(mem2,Encoding.UTF8)
            'streamMe.Write(value)
            'StreamMe.Close()
            'mem2.Position=0

            Dim gz As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(xstream, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)

            Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(gz)
            x = sr.ReadLine

            sr.Close()
            'End Using

            Decompress = x
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I verified the string I sent over contains the correct values from my VBScript.  However, its says the header is bad.

The above code has to be compiled for testing

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:library /out:"%userprofile%\desktop\t.dll" "%userprofile%\desktop\t.txt" /verbose
```

Then registered

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm" /codebase "%userprofile%\desktop\t.dll" /tlb:"%userprofile%\desktop\t.tlb" /v
```

Then invoked

```
c:\windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe old.vbs
```

I put code in to read the contents from a file, even though that is not the end goal.  When I did that the file decompressed correctly.

```
Dim xstream As New MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value))
```

This line hear seems to be incorrectly converting my string to a stream.

The goal is to send a compressed string and return a uncompressed string.

The code above is invoked with this code

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Set wso = CreateObject("WindowScriptingObject")
Dim objStream
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile "e:\download\result.gz"
'objStream.Charset = "Windows-1252" 
x = objStream.Read(900)
objStream.Close

For i=1 To Len(x) 
    t = t & Chr(AscW(Mid(x, i, 1)) And 255)
    t = t & Chr((AscW(Mid(x, i, 1)) And 65280)/256)
Next
MsgBox wso.Decompress(t), , "vbs"
```

I tried this, and even converted the string to base64 to get it work.

```
Dim gzBuffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(value)
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        Dim msgLength As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0)
        ms.Write(gzBuffer, 4, gzBuffer.Length - 4)

        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(msgLength - 1) {}
        ms.Position = 0
        Using zipStream As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
              zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        End Using
    Decompress=System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End Using
```

The data did not get converted correctly as I still have magic number in GZip header is not correct.

Dumped base64 encoded value into online decoder, and the string I passed in matches to decoded value.

Version 2
Forces me to base64 encode it, but then it works.
How do I remove this annoyance.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports System.Text

Namespace WindowScriptingObject
    <Guid("7448E08D-ED0F-4E23-B528-91937BB41756"), _
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
        Public Interface _WindowScriptingObject
        <DispId(1)> Function Decompress(ByVal value as String) As String
    End Interface

    <Guid("B146BF9E-78FC-4DB0-ABFE-9FF026B43E4D"), _
        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), _
        ProgId("WindowScriptingObject")> Public Class WindowScriptingObject
    Implements _WindowScriptingObject

    Public WindowScriptingObject()
        Public Function Decompress(ByVal value as string) As String Implements _WindowScriptingObject.Decompress
            Dim x As String
            '     on error resume next
    Dim gzBuffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(value)
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        Dim msgLength As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0)
        ms.Write(gzBuffer, 0, gzBuffer.Length)

        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(msgLength - 1) {}
        ms.Position = 0
        Using zipStream As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
              zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        End Using
    Decompress=System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End Using
'            Dim xstream As New MemoryStream(value.ToArray())
            Dim mem2 As New IO.MemoryStream()
            'Dim streamMe As New StreamWriter(mem2,Encoding.UTF8)
            'streamMe.Write(value)
            'StreamMe.Close()
            'mem2.Position=0

            'Dim gz As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(xstream, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)

            'Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(gz)
           ' x = sr.ReadLine

            'sr.Close()
            'End Using

            'Decompress = x
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Update this code works except the output size is 500K, and there's only 3100 bytes of text.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports System.Text

Namespace WindowScriptingObject
    <Guid("7448E08D-ED0F-4E23-B528-91937BB41756"), _
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
        Public Interface _WindowScriptingObject
        <DispId(1)> Function Decompress(ByVal value as string) As String
    End Interface

    <Guid("B146BF9E-78FC-4DB0-ABFE-9FF026B43E4D"), _
        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), _
        ProgId("WindowScriptingObject")> Public Class WindowScriptingObject
    Implements _WindowScriptingObject

    Public WindowScriptingObject()
        Public Function Decompress(ByVal value as string) As String Implements _WindowScriptingObject.Decompress
            '     on error resume next
    Dim gzBuffer() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.Getbytes(value)

    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        Dim msgLength As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0)
        ms.Write(gzBuffer, 0, gzBuffer.Length)
 msgbox(msgLength)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(msgLength - 1) {}
        ms.Position = 0

        Using zipStream As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
              zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        End Using
    Decompress=System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End Using

        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

For some reason msgLength is 559,903 in size, and the decompressed text is roughly 3100 bytes.  This means BitConverter.toint32 is malfunctioning as gzBuffer is 865 bytes.  The final output size is only know to the GZIPStream function as the text is compressed an the input size has no correlation to the output size.

The other question(s)

1. can this be coded more efficiently?
2. What can I do to prevent malicious code injection?
3. Limit output to the correct size?
4. If I add new functions do I need more Guid's?
5. How do I generate a new Guid?
6. In code block #3 I convert X to a string t and transfer value without conversion.

The output size seems to be based on bad information.

```
intOutputLength=zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
End Using
Decompress=System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, intOutputLength)
```

At least this reduces the amount of data return to the main program.

```
Dim msgLength As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0)
```

If I read this correctly the msgLength is determined by the first 4 characters of the input stream?  Since the GZip header is always 1f 8b 08 00 this seems to be a horrible idea.  If the output is every greater than 559k seems like a buffer overflow just waiting to happen.

I think this solves the terrible buffer size issue.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports System.Text


Namespace WindowScriptingObject
    <Guid("7448E08D-ED0F-4E23-B528-91937BB41756"), _
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
        Public Interface _WindowScriptingObject
        <DispId(1)> Function Decompress(ByVal value as string) As String
    End Interface


    <Guid("B146BF9E-78FC-4DB0-ABFE-9FF026B43E4D"), _
        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), _
        ProgId("WindowScriptingObject")> Public Class WindowScriptingObject
    Implements _WindowScriptingObject


    Public WindowScriptingObject()
        Public Function Decompress(ByVal value as string) As String Implements _WindowScriptingObject.Decompress
            '     on error resume next
    Dim gzBuffer() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.Getbytes(value)
    dim intOutputLength as integer
    Dim intBlock as integer
    Decompress=""
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        Dim msgLength As Integer = 4096
        ms.Write(gzBuffer, 0, gzBuffer.Length)

        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4096) {}
        ms.Position = 0

        Using zipStream As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
        intOutputLength=0
        intBlock=4096
        while intBlock=4096
              intBlock=zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            Decompress+=System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, intBlock)
            intOutputLength+=intBlock
        end while 
        End Using

    End Using

        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: There's no such thing as converting a `String` to a `Stream`. You create a `Stream`, convert the `String` to a `Byte` array and then write the `Byte` array to the `Stream`. When you go from `String` to `Byte` array, you must specify an encoding. If you transmit the resulting binary data and want to convert back to text afterwards, you need to be using the same encoding in both directions. The most likely issue is that you are not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  You could be right, but how do I change my code to get a working solution?  The source is a gzip compressed(binary), and the output is text.

Comment: You do some research on text encoding and make sure that you're using compatible encoding at each end. .NET offers several encodings as standard via the `System.Text.Encoding` class. Do you know what they all actually mean? If you're having issues with encoding, you should find out. Do you know exactly what encoding that VBS code you posted corresponds to? Again, you should find out.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  The source is straight binary, not UTF anything.  Therefore, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value), seems unsuitable for the job, but what do I use in its place.  I know what UTF is (a pain in the ...) taking 2 or more bytes to represent a single character so you can have every character in every language.  I spent at least 2 days getting this far.  I have tried(googled) dozens of ways to get my binary string into a stream, and they fail.

Comment: @cybernard What exactly is "straight binary", as jmcilhinney has already said the encodings have to match.

Comment: Just to be clear here: my understanding is you need to process gzip data from vbscript. Since vbscript never received native support for gzip, and is now dying so it never will, you're hoping to write a .Net method you can call from vbscript that can decompress the gzip data for you. So basically any solution that allows you to decompress the gzip data will be okay, is that correct?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn basically **BlueMonkMN** has the right idea.  But yes that is the correct idea.  It must receive a string, not a file, and return a string.  Except for the "hope" part because the process 90% complete and I have working prototype code.  I will spend most of tomorrow working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get your code working by changing the VB.NET function and interface to look like this (mainly changing the parameter type):

```
<Guid("7448E08E-ED0F-4E23-B528-91937BB41756"),
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)>
Public Interface _WindowScriptingObject
   <DispId(1)> Function Decompress(ByVal value As Byte()) As String
End Interface

Public Function Decompress(ByVal value As Byte()) As String Implements _WindowScriptingObject.Decompress
   Using xstream As New MemoryStream(value)
      Using gz As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(xstream, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
         Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(gz)
            Return sr.ReadLine()
         End Using
      End Using
   End Using
End Function
```

My test VBS looks like this

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Dim wso
Set wso = CreateObject("WindowScriptingObject")
Dim objStream, x
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile "c:\users\bluem\desktop\Notes.txt.gz"
x = objStream.Read(342737)
objStream.Close
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine wso.Decompress((x))
```

I'm not entirely sure why I needed to enclose the x parameter in two sets of parentheses, but I think it has something to do with forcing the parameter to be passed by value instead of by reference and helps it convert to a byte array. I was getting an error before I added the extra pair of parentheses.

**Edit:**
To answer some of your other questions:

- I don't think you need to create a new GUID for a new function, only for a new interface or class.
- To create a new GUID you can just copy an existing one and change part of it (to digits between 0 and F inclusive) to be unique, or you can go to https://www.guidgenerator.com/ or you can select "Create GUID" from Visual Studio's Tools menu.
- If you can clarify your data length problem based on the new code (if a problem still exists), I might be able to answer.

Comment: Ok, this looks pretty good.  I will do testing tomorrow.  However, how can I add error handling?  Say someone passes in a string of a 00, now gzip emits an error that needs to be handled and passed back.  Also what happens if x = objStream.Read(342737) is reduced to say Read(1000) because the file is larger it will generate an error that I will need to handle.

Comment: Yes your vb.net code is tested and good.  I don't know why but without the ((x)) I get access denied.  I tried every combination of byval,byRef,value,value(), byte,and byte() I could thing of to no available.  However, it saves me from inverting my buffer manually so I am keeping it.

Comment: @cybernard 342737 was just for testing. You should use adReadAll to read whatever is in the stream instead of a fixed length. You can handle errors in VBScript with On Error Resume Next and in VB.NET with `try` and `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been too long since I've written vbscript, so I don't know enough anymore to give fixes. However, I can point out some *serious flaws* in the vbscript part of this code.

It starts by reading up to 900 bytes from a `.gz` file, regardless of the actual length of file. Anything longer than a mere 900 bytes will be not read.

It performs this read in binary mode. Binary mode ignores any character set or encoding info, and just reads raw bytes, which is appropriate for a `.gz` file. However, the next thing that happens with this data is using the `Len()` function, which is for **strings**, not binary data; `Len()` is **not** the appropriate function here. Additionally, the data is next used in the `For` loop via the `Mid()` function. `Mid()` is likewise intended **only for strings**, and the `x` variant is *not a string*. vbscript string objects are more than just the raw characters; they include meta data for things like encoding, length, and character buffers, and those string functions rely on the objects being constructed properly with all metadata.

There's *no way* this vbscript produces correct results. Until that is resolved, there's no point in even looking at the vb.net code. Again, I'm too far gone to suggest a real solution, but I recommend trying to pass an unaltered byte array to the .Net side, rather than a string.